# Pull out image html from a php string containing the output

Tags: php, string, image

I have php variable which when echoed, blurts out the html. But I was to (somehow!) just get the image code out. Essentially, I want to do a grep on the variable for the image code.

How can I do this? Everything I've tried (stripos, strstr) doesn't work because it prints it all out in html. How can I first just output the code in plain text and not html?

Thanks

Comment: Use preg_match with regular expression

Comment: [link]http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ This was in another thread and looks like it would be useful for your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the HTML the variable contains, I would either

- call the `strip_tags` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php
- load the HTML into a DOM object and navigate your way to the desired information. Built-in DOM for PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

  - you can then try to find an element with either `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementById`

Where is the info you're looking for located exactly? Maybe you could post an example.

Comment: This is really good! Loaded up my dom document but I can't figure out a way to search. I simply want to replace the image code that it has in there, do you have any sugguestions?